# How to retrieve single-valued navigation properties for an entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I want to update parent relationships for specified entity. The problem is when I query N:1 refs I get referencing attributes that is not always a single-valued navigation property. I do not know how can I distinguish is the attribute `parentcustomerid` referencing to an account or to a contact entity. So the question is: How can I properly get single-valued navigation property for my specified entity to be able update it using request to PATCH  `api/data/v9.0/contacts({id})` with the body:

> {"single-valued navigation property@odata.bind" :
>   "/{accounts or contacts}({id})"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a HTTP Request, add **Prefer: odata.include-annotations="*"** to your HTTP Request Headers. This way the response not only will have a *_[Field Name]_value* field with the Id but also a *_[Field Name]_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname* with the logical name that you look for.

This is an example of a response for a request querying parentcustomerid of a specific contact without the header:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/$metadata#contacts(_parentcustomerid_value)",
"value": [
    {
        "_parentcustomerid_value": "bdeb86af-7e1c-e811-a837-000d3ac085f9",
        "contactid": "b050f3bb-dbf7-e811-a98a-000d3ac02bae"
    }
]
```

}

And this is an example of a response for the same request with the header added:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/$metadata#contacts(_parentcustomerid_value)",
"value": [
    {
       "_parentcustomerid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.associatednavigationproperty": "parentcustomerid_account",
        "_parentcustomerid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname": "account",
        "_parentcustomerid_value": "bdeb86af-7e1c-e811-a837-000d3ac085f9",
        "contactid": "b050f3bb-dbf7-e811-a98a-000d3ac02bae"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: For noobs like me: Prefer is the key of the header, odata.include-annotations=* is the value. So for restsharp: request.AddHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=*");